# CS50 Vigenere's Cipher: Can't fix the problem with the spaces in the plaintext

Tags: c, cs50

I'm having a problem with my code, which is supposed to be the 
    Vigenere's cipher from Harvard's CS50 program. I have met all the 
    requirements, except when the key is "baz" and the plaintext is "hello, 
    world!". Because there is a comma and a space, my code accepts that, and 
    shifts from z to a to b, etc. I want it to ignore the spaces and 
    punctuation so that the "b" "a" "z" only change for the characters. 
    You should only have to look at the first "else if" line, as that is
    when the plaintext is longer than the key, and the key will have to
    alternate. 
    Please help! I've been on this problem for hours, and I can't figure out 
    the solution.

```
https://gyazo.com/3a7b3e692d210262ae15f580b10f296d
https://gyazo.com/0b25bfc010d937840f09ff4294d0dd41
https://gyazo.com/c1b85208ecae1b9ad57d48d5b5af59b5
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string key = argv[1];
        int key_length = strlen(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++)
        {
            key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < key_length; k++)
        {
            if (key[k] < 'A' || key[k] > 'Z')
            {
                printf("Not a valid key!\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++)
        {
            key[i] = key[i] - 'A';
        }

        string plain = get_string("Plaintext: ");

        int plain_length = strlen(plain);
        if (key_length == plain_length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++)
            {
                if (islower(plain[i]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[i]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[i]++;
                        if (plain[i] > 'z')
                        {
                            plain[i] = 'a';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isupper(plain[i]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[i]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[i]++;
                        if (plain[i] > 'Z')
                        {
                            plain[i] = 'A';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("ciphertext: %s\n", plain);
        }
        else if (key_length < plain_length)
        {
            float truncate_not = plain_length / key_length;
            int truncate = trunc(truncate_not);
            int mod = strlen(plain) % key_length;
            for (int i = 0; i < truncate; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < key_length; k++)
                {
                    int pos = k + (i * key_length);
                    if (islower(plain[pos]))
                    {
                        for (int q = 0; q < key[k]; q++)
                        {
                            plain[pos]++;
                            if (plain[pos] > 'z')
                            {
                                plain[pos] = 'a';
                            }
                        }
                        printf("%c\n", plain[pos]);
                    }
                    else if (isupper(plain[pos]))
                    {
                        for (int q = 0; q < key[k]; q++)
                        {
                            plain[pos]++;
                            if (plain[pos] > 'Z')
                            {
                                plain[pos] = 'A';
                            }
                        }
                        printf("%c\n", plain[pos]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("error\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < mod; j++)
            {
                int pos = j + (truncate * key_length);
                if (islower(plain[pos]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[j]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[pos]++;
                        if (plain[pos] > 'z')
                        {
                            plain[pos] = 'a';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (isupper(plain[pos]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[j]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[pos]++;
                        if (plain[pos] > 'Z')
                        {
                            plain[pos] = 'A';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    plain[j] = plain[j];
                }
            }
            printf("ciphertext: %s\n", plain);
        }
        else
        {
            int mod = plain_length % key_length;
            for (int i = 0; i < mod; i++)
            {
                if (islower(plain[i]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[i]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[i]++;
                        if (plain[i] > 'z')
                        {
                            plain[i] = 'a';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isupper(plain[i]))
                {
                    for (int q = 0; q < key[i]; q++)
                    {
                        plain[i]++;
                        if (plain[i] > 'Z')
                        {
                            plain[i] = 'A';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("ciphertext: %s\n", plain);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

Actual results: iekmo, wnslc!
Expected results: iekmo, vprke!
As you can see, my code shifted the "baz", when it shouldn't have in the 
space and comma places.
```

Comment: I truly despise the CS50 course and the `<cs50.h>`. For example here the `string` can be `char *` and there is no notice that the characters given to `is*` functions need to be unsigned chars.

Comment: I would split this to several functions with names, describing what they are intended for. I would also add comments why specific parts of code are as they are. And I would never refer to images outside StackOverflow. Please post text instead.

Comment: Well, yes. I haven't gone for design or making it easy to read. I just want to get the core functionality down first before I start adding comments and stuff. Could anyone help me with my specific problem that I mentioned above?

Comment: Echoing @AnttiHaapala here.  **Do not use CS50's bogus `string`**.  It confuses how you use `char *` strings and makes understanding C much more difficult.

Comment: Use CS50's string. It is not bogus. It is an appropriate abstraction for the early problems in the course. It will be replaced in later lectures/psets by "the real thing", ie `malloc` and `calloc` and `free` , oh my! (@AndrewHenle)

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Sure it is.  [It teaches totally incorrect usages](https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/3qcx7v/questions_about_strings/).  It conflates pointers and arrays with simple integer-type lvalue objects.  All of that must later be unlearned.  It's like teaching a first-grader that `2 + 2 = 5`, then in second grade saying, "Nope, we lied to you!" What good does that do? And dynamic memory allocate with `malloc()` *et al* is orthogonal to obfuscating a basic C type.

Comment: Yes, well we haven’t learned about char* and the other things yet in the course. Please just use the syntax I used to tell me what I have to fix, not the problem with how the course teaches the language.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I fixed the problems!

Answer (score 1):

The overriding problem in this program is tying `key_length` to `plain_length`. They are discrete and must be treated separately; they "move" at different rates and should use separate and distinct indices.

First I suggest you [rewatch the walkthrough.](https://docs.cs50.net/2017/fall/psets/2/vigenere/vigenere.html#walkthrough) You probably want to write out (yes, pencil and paper) the "baz" example using the same format that Zamyla does with the "panda" example. And then write pseudo-code.

You will probably have to abandon much of the code you have written; generally this pset can be done with one loop that cycles through the plaintext by index, and then manages the keyword index independently within that loop.

Comment: It is possible to do these practice sets without watching the walkthrough correct?

Comment: Yes it is possible.